# Initialize array from another array

Tags: python

how can I do this the correct way?

```
a = ['1','2']
b = []
for value in a:
    b.append(value)
```

I need to do this because I want to change values in a but I want to keep them in b.
When I do `b = a` it seems to just set pointers to the values in a.

Comment: `b = list(a)` will create a copy of list a. Also, in `python` these are referred to as list, not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate reference (pointing to the same list):

```
b = a
```

Soft copy (all the same elements, but a different list):

```
b = a[:]      # special version of the slice notation that produces a softcopy
b = list(a)   # the list() constructor takes an iterable. It can create a new list from an existing list
b = a.copy()  # the built-in collections classes have this method that produces a soft copy
```

For a deep copy (copies of all elements, rather than just the same elements) you'd want to invoke the built-in `copy` module.:

```
from copy import deepcopy

b = deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with :

```
b = a[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to copy a list to another list.

```
b = a.copy()
```